# FCM Data messages are not working properly

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using data messages where we can send messages even when the app is killed or in background or in foreground. I am using FCM .
But in my case sometimes my app does not get those messages . I am sending messages from app to app. Sometimes the app get messages even when it is killed or removed from background but again , sometimes it wont. 
When i open the app , then suddenly the message appears. I am opening activities when a particular message is received . I know that data messages are used for sending messages even when the app is killed or in background or in foreground , but i am having problem like this . please help !..
I want it to be absolute .
I just want my app to be connected to FirebaseMessagingServices always , even when it is killed. I don't know about services and some says that i need to create a foreground services . How to create it and implement to FirebaseMessagingServices .?

**MYFirebaseMessaging.java**

```js
package com.example.praful.ubercoustomer.Service;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.praful.ubercoustomer.AcceptedWindow;
import com.example.praful.ubercoustomer.Common.Common;
import com.example.praful.ubercoustomer.CompanycancelledtheBooking;
import com.example.praful.ubercoustomer.DeclinedWindow;
import com.example.praful.ubercoustomer.Helper.NotificationHelper;
import com.example.praful.ubercoustomer.Onthewayandimreached;
import com.example.praful.ubercoustomer.R;
import com.example.praful.ubercoustomer.RateActivity;
import com.example.praful.ubercoustomer.VerifyingCompletedBooking;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

import java.util.Map;

public class MyFirebaseMessaging extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(final RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {


        if (remoteMessage.getData() != null) {
            Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
            String title = data.get("title");
            final String companyName = data.get("CompanyName");
            final String BookingIdC = data.get("BookingIdC");
            final String BookingIdT = data.get("BookingIdT");
            final String companyPhone = data.get("CompanyPhone");
            final String companyRates = data.get("CompanyRates");
            final String companyId = data.get("CompanyId");
            final String Date = data.get("Date");
            final String companyIdC = data.get("companyIdC");
            final String Time = data.get("Time");
            final String Id = data.get("Id");
            final String Address = data.get("Address");
            final String Bookingid = data.get("Bookingid");
            final String TimeCB = data.get("TimeCB");
            final String DateCB = data.get("DateCB");
            final String EventType = data.get("EventType");
            final String messageCB = data.get("messageCB");
            final String AddressCB = data.get("AddressCB");
            final String companythatcancelledthebooking = data.get("CompanyNamethatcancelledthebooking");

            final String message = data.get("message");
            //  remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle() = title and  remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody() = message
            if (title != null && title.equals("Cancel")) {
                Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MyFirebaseMessaging.this, DeclinedWindow.class);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                        startActivity(intent);

                        Common.isCompanyFound = false;
                        Common.companyId = "";
                        Toast.makeText(MyFirebaseMessaging.this, "" + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            } else if (title != null && title.equals("cancelAdvanceBooking")) {
                Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), CompanycancelledtheBooking.class);
                        intent.putExtra("DateCB", DateCB);
                        intent.putExtra("TimeCB", TimeCB);
                        intent.putExtra("messageCB", messageCB);
                        intent.putExtra("AddressCB", AddressCB);
                        intent.putExtra("EventType", EventType);
                        intent.putExtra("Id", Id);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                        startActivity(intent);

                        Common.isCompanyFound = false;
                        Common.companyId = "";
                        Toast.makeText(MyFirebaseMessaging.this, "" + messageCB, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

            } else if (title != null && title.equals("Accept")) {


                Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MyFirebaseMessaging.this, AcceptedWindow.class);
                        intent.putExtra("Date", Date);
                        intent.putExtra("Time", Time);
                        intent.putExtra("Address", Address);
                        intent.putExtra("companyName", companyName);
                        intent.putExtra("companyPhone", companyPhone);
                        intent.putExtra("companyRates", companyRates);
                        intent.putExtra("companyId", companyId);
                        intent.putExtra("Bookingid", Bookingid);
                        intent.putExtra("EventType", EventType);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                        startActivity(intent);
                        Common.isCompanyFound = false;
                        Common.companyId = "";


                        Toast.makeText(MyFirebaseMessaging.this, "" + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

            } else if (title != null && title.equals("Arrived")) {
                Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
                            showArrivedNotifAPI26(message);
                        else
                            showArrivedNotif(message);

                    }
                });
            } else if (title != null && title.equals("Completed")) {

                openRateactivity(message);
            } else if (title != null && title.equals("completedAdvancebooking")) {
                Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MyFirebaseMessaging.this, VerifyingCompletedBooking.class);
                        intent.putExtra("BookingIdC", BookingIdC);
                        intent.putExtra("message", message);
                        intent.putExtra("companyid", companyIdC);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                        startActivity(intent);

                    }
                });
            } else if (title != null && title.equals("Ontheway")) {
                Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MyFirebaseMessaging.this, Onthewayandimreached.class);
                        intent.putExtra("message", message);
                        intent.putExtra("BookingIdT", BookingIdT);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                        startActivity(intent);

                    }
                });
            } else if (title != null && title.equals("Reached")) {
                Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MyFirebaseMessaging.this, Onthewayandimreached.class);
                        intent.putExtra("message", message);
                        intent.putExtra("BookingIdT", BookingIdT);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                        startActivity(intent);

                    }
                });
            }

        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private void showArrivedNotifAPI26(String body) {
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 0,
                new Intent(), PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationHelper notificationHelper = new NotificationHelper(getBaseContext());
        Notification.Builder builder = notificationHelper.getUberNotification("Arrived", body, contentIntent, defaultSound);
        notificationHelper.getManager().notify(1, builder.build());

    }

    private void openRateactivity(String body) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, RateActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void showArrivedNotif(String body) {
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 0,
                new Intent(), PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getBaseContext());
        builder.setAutoCancel(true)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis()).
                setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_camera)
                .setContentTitle("Arrived")
                .setContentText(body)
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent);

        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.notify(1, builder.build());
    }

}
```

**MyFirebaseIdService**

```js
package com.example.praful.ubercoustomer.Service;

import com.example.praful.ubercoustomer.Common.Common;
import com.example.praful.ubercoustomer.Model.Token;
import com.example.praful.ubercoustomer.Common.Common;
import com.example.praful.ubercoustomer.Model.Token;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService;

public class MyFirebaseIdService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        super.onTokenRefresh();

        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        updateTokenToServer(refreshedToken);

    }

    private void updateTokenToServer(String refreshedToken) {

        FirebaseDatabase db =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference tokens = db.getReference(Common.token_table);

        Token token = new Token(refreshedToken);
        if(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() != null)
            tokens.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue(token);

    }
}
```

Comment: Please update your question with your FirebaseMessagingService#onMessageReceived implementation.

Comment: Please check i have updates my MyFirebaseMessaging class

Comment: Any words to say ?

Comment: Check my answer and please ensure that you implement `onTokenRefresh` and  save refreshed token to your DB, when FCM update device token for any reason.

Comment: @PrafulBuyakar Khaled Lela's answer seems to be correct. If you intend to unse Cloud Firestore, the new database from Google, I have exaplained in one of my **[tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0AmXOWOam729bC47v0d0Ohee)** step by step, how you can send **[notifications](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6RzB4HXzQyA&t=3s&list=PLn2n4GESV0AmXOWOam729bC47v0d0Ohee&index=17)** using Cloud Firestore and Node.js. In this case Android Os will handle the notification for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- First check this remote message contains payload, May be payload  get corrupt for any reason.

  ```
  public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
  private static final String TAG = "REMOTE_MSG";

  @Override
  public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
      if (remoteMessage == null)
          return;

      // check if message contains a notification payload.
      if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
          Log.e(TAG, "Notification body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
          createNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification());
      }

      // check if message contains a data payload
      if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
          Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
          Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
      }
  }
  ```
- **DON'T** forgent to update your FCM device token on your DB.

  ```
  public class MyFirebaseInstanceIdService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
  private static final String TAG = "FCM_ID";

  @Override
  public void onTokenRefresh() {
      // get hold of the registration token
      String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
      // lg the token
      Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
      sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
  }
  private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
      // implement this method if you want to store the token on your server
  }
  }
  ```

**Update 1**

- As mentioned [Firebase repo issue](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/368) expected that issue to be related to device, Please try another device aspect.

**Update 2** *Quote from [firebase repo](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/368) contributor* **kroikie**

> FCM does not process messages if an app is "killed" or force stopped.
>   When a user kills an app it is an indication that the user does not
>   want the app running so that app should not run till the user
>   explicitly starts it again.
>
> Note that swiping an app from recents list should NOT "kill" or force
>   stop it. If messages are not being received after swiping from recents
>   list then please identify these devices and we will work with the
>   manufactures to correct this behaviour.
>
> Only being able to handle messages when the app is in the foreground
>   or background is working as intended.

**Update 3**

- **Try hacks mentioned on this issue.**

  1. Inserting this lines in Manifest.xml

     ```
     <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
     ```
  2. It is because of DOZE mode and battery optimization,you just have to turn off battery optimization for all apps or particular app. Go to Settings>> apps >> select your app>> battery>>
     battery optimization> select your app>> select don't optimise.
     Problem solved.
  3. Now (for APP IS CLOSED case) I write Notification text to file and read this text if extras == null and notificationText.txt is exists... its stupid solution but it works. How can I catch this extras when app is closed in other way.

**Update 4**

- Try to [Setting the priority](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#setting-the-priority-of-a-message) of a message,
- Disable [Battery Optimization](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby#support_for_other_use_cases)

> Users can manually configure the whitelist in Settings > Battery >
>   Battery Optimization. Alternatively, the system provides ways for apps
>   to ask users to whitelist them.
>
> An app can fire the ACTION_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS intent
>   to take the user directly to the Battery Optimization, where they can
>   add the app. An app holding the REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS
>   permission can trigger a system dialog to let the user add the app to
>   the whitelist directly, without going to settings. The app fires a
>   ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS Intent to trigger the
>   dialog. The user can manually remove apps from the whitelist as
>   needed.

- Programmatically open Battery Optimization, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32150246/1283715).

**TAKE CARE ABOUT THIS**

> Before asking the user to add your app to the whitelist, make sure the
>   app matches the acceptable use cases for whitelisting.
>
> **Note**: 
>   Google Play policies prohibit apps from requesting direct exemption from
>   Power Management features in Android 6.0+ (Doze and App Standby)
>   unless the core function of the app is adversely affected.

**Update 5**

- Check [PowerManager.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager#isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations()) from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39256632/1283715).
- When disable battery optimization, Consider to check first if it's **already disabled** then no need to show dialog, else you can show dialog.

  ```
   /**
    * return false if in settings "Not optimized" and true if "Optimizing battery use"
    */
  private boolean checkBatteryOptimized() {
  final PowerManager pwrm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
  try {
      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
          return !pwrm.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(getBaseContext().getPackageName());
      }
  }catch (Exception ignored){}
  return false;
  }

  private void startBatteryOptimizeDialog(){
   try {
  Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS);
  intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:PUT_YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME_HERE"));
  startActivity(intent);

   } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
  }
  ```

Comment: Hmm, but i dont think this is the reason because the app gets the message even after getting killed but after like 10min it wont. Thats my problem... Any ways thanks for reply and ask your needs to solve this problem .Any thing is appreciated.

Comment: Check my answer update, please ensure that you implement onTokenRefresh and save refreshed token to your DB, when FCM update device token for any reason

Comment: Can u tell how WhatsApp work even if the app is killed? Just hoping to get some clues ...

Comment: Try hacks mentioned on this issue.

Comment: adding these two permissions also in manifest

"uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"
"uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"

Comment: Quote text is said by firebase contributor **kroikie**

Comment: Yeah i observed that

Comment: "But when app is killed I receive notification and after click on it- Extras == null." Im not even getting the notification sometimes,  sometimes is my problem.

Comment: It receives fine for 10 to 20 min after app is killed but i want it to work for hours  , that is my consent. Anyway i have to wait for 30min after adding permissions.  I'll let u know

Comment: Is there any code to do update 3 number 2 ? Like opening a dialog asking to not optimised while opening the app ?

Comment: Please check my **Update 4** hope that will help you to handle your issue.

Comment: First of all i want to thank you .Thanks very much for considering this problem for this much of time..Update 4 is really help ful out of 4 . I think i need to set up  JobIntentService or FJD job. Actually iam very much beginner in services and know only about FCM  , any sites which explaines explicitely about JobIntentService or FJD job would help me

Comment: Stoping Optimization did the work !!!! Thank you very much !!! Please accept my Friend req in FAce book . I wanna be in contact for future help ...

Comment: Your are welcome for sure!!!, BTW check my **update 5** for check battery optimization before opining battery optimization screen.

Comment: If u know about BroadCastReceiver Please tell how to code it . I got to know that they work even when app is killed and i want to know about it . Connecting FirebaseMessagingService --> BroadcastReceiver --> Activity

Comment: Please ask another question, for other to make use of question and answer